# JS - filtering certain value from the array

Tags: javascript, filter

I have a problem on which I was stuck for awhile but I already solved it but I still need insight as to why it occurs.

The problem wants me to subtract one list from another and return the resulting
`array_diff([1,1,2],[1]) == [1]`.

So I decided to use array.filter() for the problem and this is what I came up with:

```
function array_diff(a, b) {
    for (i in b){
        a = a.filter(function(c){ if (c != b[i]){ return c; }}); 
    }
    return a;
}
```

It runs fine until the array includes zero. 
For example: `array_diff([0,3,4],[3])`. I got `[4]` instead of `[0,4]`. Why is that?

My solution later is to map a new array and filter null val and that works.

```
function array_diff(a, b) {
    for (i in b){
        a = a.map(function(c){ if (c != b[i]){ return c; }}); 
    }
    var filtered = a.filter(function (el) {
        return el != null;
    });

    return filtered;
}
```

But why does filter work like that. I would like to know.

Comment: Please don't use [`for ... in`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476) for arrays.

Comment: @Yoshi hi yoshi, why would i not use that for array?

Comment: Follow the link ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a shorter way to do it, using `filter` and `includes`:

```js
const a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const b = [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5];

const arrayDiff = (a, b) => a.filter(elem => !b.includes(elem));

console.log(arrayDiff(a, b));
```

Answer (score 2):

The callback to the `filter` method needs to return a *Boolean* value, which is used to decide whether to keep the element or not. Your code:

```
a = a.filter(function(c){ if (c != b[i]){ return c; }});
```

Is returning the element itself. Since JS expects a boolean, it is converting the number to a bool. In particular, `0` is converted to `false`, so is excluded.

Just do this instead:

```
a = a.filter(function(c){ return (c != b[i]);});
```